# Summation Notation: $i<j$

Tags: summation

Is this true? $$ \sum\limits_{i<j} x_ix_j = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^j x_ix_j$$
$i, j = 1,\ldots,n$

And on the left hand side, how can you tell when it stops?

Comment: it is usually implied that $j$ goes up to some value $n$ which should be clear from the context. It may be the dimension of a matrix or a vector for example

Comment: That's usually shorthand, with the assumption of the start and end values. You'll sometimes see the more verbose: $$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} x_ix_j$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite: you are summing terms $x_jx_j$ on the right that don't appear on the left... The correct formula is $$\sum_{j=2}^n\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\,x_ix_j$$

Answer (score 1):

You are close! Notice that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^j x_ix_j$ contains the term $x_jx_j\forall j \leq n$

$$ \sum\limits_{i<j} x_ix_j = \sum\limits_{j=2}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{j-1} x_ix_j$$

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Iverson summation:
$$
\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n[i<j] x_ix_j=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}x_ix_j=\sum_{j=2}^n\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}x_ix_j
$$
where $[i<j]$ is an Iverson bracket equals one if $i<j$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: In the last double summation on the right, for the case $j=1$ the sum over $i$ will run from $i=1$ up to $i = j-1 = 0$--that is, the sum will have no terms. So you can just as well start at $j=2$, with the same result in the end. (I'm not saying the formula above is wrong; technically, $j=1$ works too for the reason I just gave.)

Comment: Thanks... I didn't notice that... actually was wondering if the other answers had a typo.

Comment: It's redundant to use the indicator function on an Iverson bracket. In any event, indicator functions and Iverson brackets don't return truth values, they return $1$ or $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote
$\sum\limits_{i<j} x_ix_j = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^j x_ix_j$

To change the left side
so that is the same as the right,
I would change it to
$\sum\limits_{1\le i\le j \le n} x_ix_j
$.